# Stream PHP responses word by word back to JS, without keeping full history

Tags: javascript, php, stream

I would like to stream PHP responses to JS word by word, however responses get cached:
PHP File:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    
ob_clean();
echo "Hello ";
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(2);

ob_clean();
echo "World ";
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(2);

ob_clean();
echo "!";
ob_flush();
flush();
?>
```

JS File:

```
var httpllm = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
httpllm.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(httpllm.readyState == 3)
    {
        console.log(httpllm.responseText);
    }
}

httpllm.open('POST', 'test.php', true);
httpllm.send();
```

Result:

```
-> Hello
-> Hello World
-> Hello World !
```

What I want:

```
-> Hello
-> World
-> !
```

What am I missing to only send / receive one word and not the full history at each response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually handle the SSE using the `EventSource`

example:

```js
var eventSource = new EventSource('sse.php');

eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
};
```

here the `onmessage` treats each message separately!

The `readystatechange` event is triggered multiple times as the `XMLHttpRequest` progresses through different states. It doesn't necessarily correspond to individual messages or chunks of data received from the server. Instead, it is often used to track the overall progress of the request.

In your case, when you use `onreadystatechange` and check for `xhr.readyState == 3` (which corresponds to the `LOADING` state), it means that the response body is still being received. The event will be triggered multiple times as more data arrives, and each time, you're logging the entire response text, which accumulates the content received so far.